# Chome Windows switching/flashing nonstop after unhibernation

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, debug

Earlier on I hibernated the computer when Chrome browser was running.

Now when I start-up the computer, the windows of Chrome are "flashing" nonstop. Damn Microsoft Windows. See [this 10 second video record](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B53jM4a9X2fqUi1kdmRRVHV3eFU) to see the bug because it's hard to explain in words.

(It seems like they are swapping Windows index (Window 1, Window 2, Window 3, Window N) but I've got no idea what is happening.)

Any ideas how can this problem can be fixed?

Comment: To clarify, is this still happening? Meaning every time you hibernate?

Comment: @InterLinked, Probably 10% of the times I unhibernate, I get this bug. It'll just keep flashing for hours.